# RabbitMQ Federate to Virtual Host on Same Server

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a RabbitMQ server which receives messages to an exchange within a virtual host called "ce_func", this exchange is bound to a queue called "azure_trigger".

I'd like to use Azure Functions new RabbitMQ binding to collect from Rabbit. Unfortunately, this is limited to collecting only from virtual host '/' . I was hoping that I could use Rabbit's federation functionality to automatically route to an "azure_trigger" queue within the "/" virtual host of the same server but so far I've failed.

I created a Rabbit "upstream" and "policy" applied to that upstream but I can't figure out the configuration. I have a Federation Status of "Running" but it's only checking the "ce_func" virtual host, I can't see where I can set the target exchange as the "/" virtual host.

Does anyone have any pointers please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no way to adjust the connection parameter to use a different vhost? This seems like a pretty severe limitation... have you tried changing the URI of the connection??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to deliver message between queues in different vhosts.

RabbitMQ community recommend to use [Shovel plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) to handle this situation:

> The source and destination can be on the same broker (typically in different vhosts) or distinct brokers.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to reference any virtual host (vhost) in the in the `uri` field of the federation-upstream's configuration in the form:

```
"amqp://" [ username [ ":" password ] "@" ] host [ ":" port ] [ "/" vhost ]
```

So in simple terms you can wack the vhost on the end of the uri e.g. `amqp://localhost:5672/myvhost`... if your vhost name is blank then just make sure you include the trailing slash '/' e.g. `amqp://localhost:5672/`.

A note specific to the blank vhost from the rabbitmq docs (https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html)

> The vhost component may be absent; this is indicated by the lack of a
> "/" character following the amqp_authority. An absent vhost component
> is not equivalent to an empty (i.e. zero-length) vhost name.